# Angular Form validation based on variable not input value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am trying to write a validator that is based on an array, selectedMessages, length being greater than 0 because the values are coming from a component, app-messages-selector, when selected.

The component is in its own stepper on the form but I would like to validate that there is at least 1 value in the array before form user submits. I could only find a validator that is using controls input fields.

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
  isLinear = false;
  hide = true;

  userInfoForm: FormGroup;
  messagesForm: FormGroup;
  timeForm: FormGroup;


  popularMessages: PopularMessage[] = [];
  selectedMessages: string[] = [];
  timeSelected: string = "";

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private http: HttpService) {

    this.userInfoForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.email],
      password: ['', Validators.minLength(6)],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.minLength(6)],
      phone: ['', Validators.required],
    });

    this.messagesForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      messages: ['', Validators.required, this.messageSelectedValidator]
    })

    this.timeForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      time: ['',
        Validators.required
      ]
    });
  }

  messageSelectedValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      return this.hasValidSelectedMessage() ? null : { needsMessageSelected: true }
    };
  };

  private hasValidSelectedMessage(): boolean {
    if (this.selectedMessages.length > 0) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public selectedMessagesEmitterParent(values: string[]): void {
    this.selectedMessages = values;
  }
```

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="messagesForm" label="Messages">
      <form [formGroup]="messagesForm">
        <app-messages-selector [popularMessages]="popularMessages"
          (selectedMessagesEmitter)="selectedMessagesEmitterParent($event)">
        </app-messages-selector>

        <div>
          <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
          <button mat-raised-button matStepperNext color="primary" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
```